# User profile dependent picklist values

Tags: picklist, profile, dependent-picklist

Can I hide/show picklist values in dropdowns dependant on the user profile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Record types should provide the functionality you're looking for: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_recordtype.htm&language=en_US

> Record types allow you to offer different business processes, picklist values, and page layouts to different users.